# Usage custom namespace Flask Socket io gives an errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I've used perfect [Flask-SocketIO](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO) library with Python 3 for couple of months. Everything worked as expected until the last couple of days.

All works fine, if namespace for connection to websocket server stay default `/socket.io`. But I'm geting an error now if I trying to change namespace for connection to python flask-socketio backend. 
My *app.py*:

```
from flask import Flask, session, request, render_template, copy_current_request_context
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import flask_socketio as socketio
import ujson

async_mode = 'threading'
namespace = '/mynamespace'

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
sio = socketio.SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)

@sio.on('connect', namespace=namespace)
def connect():
    logging.info('Connected')


@sio.on('disconnect', namespace=namespace)
def disconnect():
    logging.info('Disconnected')

@app.route("/home/index")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html',
            async_mode=sio.async_mode)
```

I'm using `./main.py` to run the server, *main.py* contains:

```
from app import app, sio

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sio.run(app, debug=False)
```

My `template/index.html` contains ton of code js, but I think most valuable I loading the socketio from cdn in a head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

... and I using connect with custom namespace path, as in docs:

```
    namespace = '/mynamespace/socket.io';

    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port, 
                            {path: namespace});

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('Connected to server');
    })
```

As I understand, By default socketio library trying to connect to backend with emitting `connect` message to namespace. During loading 'index.html' template on '/home/index' route, logging the errors to console:

[image: Error on 'connect' to flask-socketio backend]

Flask server also gives and 404 error:

[image: Flask backend logs]

My best guess: at this moment it looks like something changed in client-side JS library or in chrome browser itself(few days ago I updated Chrome).

Maybe I just understood wrong one small detail. I really appreciate some help with this problem.

Stack versions:

- Python 3.7.2,
- Flask 1.0.2,
- Flask-SocketIO 3.3.1,
- [socketio.min.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.min.js)
  1.3.5,
- Google Chrome  77.0.3865.90 (64 bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `namespace` with `path`, which are completely different things. The path is the endpoint URL where the Socket.IO server is listening. The namespace is a protocol feature of Socket.IO that allows multiplexing of multiple logical connections into a single physical connection.

Comment: I completely missed this point in documentation, I think it would be helpful to add into documentation example with explanation of difference between path and namespace.